# Hover effect not covering all divs with assigned class

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a hamburger toggled menu using (short) videos as menu options. The css code was written through sass so I will include both the scss and the corresponding css code.

https://frysling.netlify.app/

All these menu options should have functioning links and a hover effect removing the black #000 overlay with a hover effect, setting the opacity of the overlay div to 0.

However, only the first (1/4) and the last (4/4) menu option have the hover effect and functioning links. The links go nowhere atm but the pointer cursor is showing on those two .footer-content divs.

I've tried rewriting the 2nd and 3rd .footer-content HTML divs to be, content aside, the same code as the functioning first and fourth div. I've also tried splitting up the classes into .footer-content-1 till four, nothing changed.

Here is the html code, i've tried to be descriptive in the comments. Forgive me for posting the entire code, I'm just not sure what detail could cause the problem:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <title>Frysling | De Noorderlijkse Wijngaard</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <!-- Logo & shopping cart -->
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" id="logo" /></a>
        <a href="#"
          ><img src="img/shopping-cart.png" alt="" id="shopping-cart"
        /></a>
        <!-- Hamburger Menu -->
        <div class="menu-wrap">
          <input type="checkbox" class="toggler" />
          <div class="hamburger"><div></div></div>
          <div class="menu">
            <div>
              <div>
                <!-- Menu Content Grid -->
                <div class="footer-grid">
                  <!-- About/Over Ons -->
                  <div class="footer-content">
                    <div class="menu-video-wrap">
                      <video
                        src="img/menu_vid_overons.mov"
                        muted
                        preload
                        autoplay
                        loop="yes"
                      ></video>
                      <div class="vid-text">
                        <a href="#"
                          ><h1>Over Ons</h1>
                          <h5>Historie en filosofie</h5></a
                        >
                      </div>
                      <div class="menu-overlay"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Our Vineyard / Onze Wijngaard -->
                  <div class="footer-content">
                    <div class="menu-video-wrap">
                      <video
                        src="img/menu_vid_wijngaard.mp4"
                        muted
                        preload
                        autoplay
                        loop="yes"
                      ></video>
                      <div class="vid-text">
                        <a href="#"
                          ><h1>Onze Wijngaard</h1>
                          <h5>Proeverijen, evenementen en vrijwilligers</h5></a
                        >
                      </div>
                      <div class="menu-overlay"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Wines / Wijnen -->
                  <div class="footer-content">
                    <div class="menu-video-wrap">
                      <video
                        src="img/menu_vid_wijnen.mp4"
                        muted
                        preload
                        autoplay
                        loop="yes"
                      ></video>
                      <div class="vid-text">
                        <a href="#"
                          ><h1>Wijnen</h1>
                          <h5>Stille en mousserende wijnen</h5></a
                        >
                      </div>
                      <div class="menu-overlay"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Contact -->
                  <div class="footer-content">
                    <div class="menu-video-wrap">
                      <video
                        src="img/menu_vid_contact.mp4"
                        autoplay
                        loop="yes"
                        muted
                        preload
                      ></video>
                      <div class="vid-text">
                        <a href="#"
                          ><h1>
                            Contact
                          </h1>
                          <h5>Neem contact op</h5>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="menu-overlay"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Showcase Hero -->
        <header id="showcase">
          <div class="showcase-overlay"></div>
          <div class="container showcase-container">
            <h1>Wijngaard de Frysling</h1>
            <p>De Noorderlijkste Wijngaard van Nederland</p>
          </div>
        </header>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the css, below I will also post the scss which appears more readable:

```
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
              box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
    }

    body {
      font-family: "Lora", sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
      max-width: 960px;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0 3rem;
    }

    #logo {
      width: 150px;
      margin-top: 1rem;
      margin-left: 3rem;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    #shopping-cart {
      margin-top: 0.5rem;
      position: absolute;
      right: 6%;
      width: 40px;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .menu-wrap {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 5%;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .menu-wrap .toggler {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .menu-wrap .hamburger {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      padding: 1rem;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
              justify-content: center;
    }

    .menu-wrap .hamburger > div {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
          -ms-flex: none;
              flex: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2.5px;
      background: #fff;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
              justify-content: center;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      transition: all 0.4s ease;
    }

    .menu-wrap .hamburger > div::before, .menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      top: -10px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2.5px;
      background: inherit;
    }

    .menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
      top: 10px;
    }

    .menu-wrap .menu {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      visibility: hidden;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
              justify-content: center;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    .menu-wrap .menu > div {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0);
              transform: scale(0);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      transition: all 0.4s ease;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
          -ms-flex: none;
              flex: none;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
              justify-content: center;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    .menu-wrap .menu > div > div {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s easy;
      transition: opacity 0.4s easy;
    }

    .menu-wrap .menu > div > div .footer-grid {
      display: -ms-grid;
      display: grid;
      -ms-grid-columns: (25vw)[4];
          grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25vw);
      -ms-grid-rows: 25vh;
          grid-template-rows: 25vh;
      grid-gap: 1rem;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    .menu-wrap .menu > div > div .footer-grid .footer-content {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    .menu-wrap .menu > div > div .footer-grid .footer-content .menu-video-wrap {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .menu-wrap .menu > div > div .footer-grid .footer-content .menu-video-wrap video {
      -o-object-fit: fill;
         object-fit: fill;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .menu-wrap .menu > div > div .footer-grid .footer-content .menu-video-wrap .menu-overlay {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: #000;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .menu-wrap .menu > div > div .footer-grid .footer-content .menu-video-wrap .menu-overlay:hover {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .menu-wrap .menu > div > div .footer-grid .footer-content .menu-video-wrap .vid-text {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 3;
      margin: 0 auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 40%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .menu-wrap .menu > div > div .footer-grid .footer-content .menu-video-wrap .vid-text a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      z-index: 3;
    }

    /* Toggler Animation */
    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
              transform: rotate(135deg);
    }

    /* Turns lines into X */
    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:before,
    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
      top: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
              transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    /* Rotate on Hover when checked */
    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover + .hamburger > div {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
              transform: rotate(225deg);
    }

    /* Show Menu */
    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu {
      visibility: visible;
    }

    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
              transform: scale(1);
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.75s;
              transition-duration: 0.75s;
    }

    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div > div {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.4s;
      transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.4s;
    }

    #showcase {
      height: 100vh;
    }

    #showcase:before {
      content: "";
      background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/39511/purple-grapes-vineyard-napa-valley-napa-vineyard-39511.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260") no-repeat center center/cover;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    #showcase .showcase-overlay {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 0;
    }

    #showcase .showcase-container {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          -ms-flex-direction: column;
              flex-direction: column;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
              justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      height: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      color: #fff;
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
    }

    #showcase .showcase-container h1 {
      line-height: 1.4;
      font-size: 4.5rem;
    }

    #showcase .showcase-container p {
      line-height: 1.4;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    /*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

Here is  the SCSS code:

```
    // Variables
    $primary-color: #f6f5e8;
    $secondary-color: green;
    $overlay-color: #333;
    $menu-speed: 0.75s;

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
    }

    body {
      font-family: "Lora", sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
      max-width: 960px;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0 3rem;
    }

    // Logo
    #logo {
      width: 150px;
      margin-top: 1rem;
      margin-left: 3rem;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    // Shopping Cart
    #shopping-cart {
      margin-top: 0.5rem;
      position: absolute;
      right: 6%;
      width: 40px;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    // Hamburger Menu
    .menu-wrap {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 5%;
      z-index: 1;
      .toggler {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        opacity: 0;
      }
      .hamburger {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        padding: 1rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        > div {
          position: relative;
          flex: none;
          width: 100%;
          height: 2.5px;
          background: #fff;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          transition: all 0.4s ease;
          &::before,
          &::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            top: -10px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 2.5px;
            background: inherit;
          }
          &::after {
            top: 10px;
          }
        }
      }
      .menu {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility: hidden;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        bottom: 0;
        > div {
          transform: scale(0);
          transition: all 0.4s ease;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          display: flex;
          flex: none;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          bottom: 0;
          > div {
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.4s easy;
            .footer-grid {
              display: grid;
              grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25vw);
              grid-template-rows: 25vh;
              grid-gap: 1rem;
              bottom: 0;
              .footer-content {
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                bottom: 0;
                .menu-video-wrap {
                  width: 100%;
                  height: 100%;
                  overflow: hidden;
                  video {
                    object-fit: fill;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                  }
                  .menu-overlay {
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 100%;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    background: #000;
                    z-index: 1;
                    opacity: 0.5;
                    &:hover {
                      opacity: 0;
                    }
                  }
                  .vid-text {
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 3;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    left: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    top: 40%;
                    text-align: center;
                    a {
                      color: #fff;
                      text-decoration: none;
                      z-index: 3;
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    /* Toggler Animation */
    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div {
      transform: rotate(135deg);
    }

    /* Turns lines into X */
    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:before,
    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
      top: 0;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    /* Rotate on Hover when checked */
    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover + .hamburger > div {
      transform: rotate(225deg);
    }

    /* Show Menu */
    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu {
      visibility: visible;
    }
    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div {
      transform: scale(1);
      transition-duration: $menu-speed;
    }

    .menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div > div {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.4s;
    }
    // Showcase
    #showcase {
      height: 100vh;
      &:before {
        content: "";
        // Placeholder background
        background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/39511/purple-grapes-vineyard-napa-valley-napa-vineyard-39511.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260")
          no-repeat center center/cover;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
      }
      .showcase-overlay {
        background: rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: 0.3);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 0;
      }
      .showcase-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
        h1 {
          line-height: 1.4;
          font-size: 4.5rem;
        }
        p {
          line-height: 1.4;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 1.5rem;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because **your main container overlaying all your elements with `z-index: 1;`**.

Try to remove `z-index` from this and you will be fine:

```css
#showcase .showcase-container {
   z-index: 1;
}
```